# Insert in Binary search tree recursively using comparison function in C

Tags: c

I am using nested structures to create a BST but I have a problem while inserting because I use a comparison function to do so!
here is my comparison function

```
int compare_doubles(const void* a, const void* b)
 {
    const double* a_ = (const double*)a;
    const double* b_ = (const double*)b;
    return (*a_ > *b_) - (*a_ < *b_);
}



 int compare_int(const void* a, const void* b)
 {
    const int* a_ = (const int*)a;
    const int* b_ = (const int*)b;
    return (*a_ > *b_) - (*a_ < *b_);
}
```

and here is the structures

```
typedef struct tree_t BinarySearchTree; //opaque structure declared on BinarySearchTree.h

struct tree_t{
    int (*comparison)(const void *, const void *);
    struct tree_t* lchild;
    struct tree_t* rchild;
    struct t_node* noeud;
};

struct t_node{
    const void *key;
    const void *data;
    City *city;
};
```

and this is my function to create a new BST

```
BinarySearchTree* newBST(int comparison_fn_t(const void *, const void *))
{
    BinarySearchTree *t = (struct tree_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_t));
    t->comparison = comparison_fn_t;
    t->lchild = t->rchild = NULL;
    t->noeud = NULL;  
    return t;
    
}
```

This is my insertion function

```
BinarySearchTree* insertInBST(BinarySearchTree* bst, const void* key, const void* value) {
    BinarySearchTree *t = bst;
    
    
    if (bst->noeud == NULL)
    {
        struct t_node* n = (struct t_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct t_node));
        t->noeud = n;
        t->noeud->data = value;
        t->noeud->key = key;
        return t;
    }

    
    if ((bst->comparison(&key,&(bst->noeud->key))) < 0){
        
        bst->lchild = insertInBST(bst->lchild, key, value);
    }
    else if ((bst->comparison(&key,&(bst->noeud->key))) >= 0){ // handle duplicate keys
        bst->rchild = insertInBST(bst->rchild, key, value);
    }
    return bst;
}
```

when I try to run my code using these tests I get segfault (core dumped)
this is my main function

````
int main()
{


    int *t =15;
    int *g = 13;
    int *j =15;
    int *k = 13;

    BinarySearchTree *root = newBST(&compare_doubles);
    insertInBST(root, k,j);
    insertInBST(root, t, g);
    
}```
````

Comment: Your comparison functions are unnecessarily complicated.  Just return *b - *a.  The next step is to compile the code with debug symbols then execute it in a debugger so you can see what line causes the crash.  You allocate a new node in insertInBST but you copy pointers for key and value which is suspicious.  The other thing likely cause is that your example uses compare_doubles but the data you use is integer pointers (int *).  There are two problems both wrong type but also I think you want to use values not pointers.  Also minimize your example to demonstrate problem (i.e. int or double).

Comment: I used it but I got an error ```error :void value not ignored as it ought to be return (*b - *a);```

Comment: You still have cast the values so I would write it as (*(double *) b - *(double *) a).

Comment: Thank you for your time but I really don't know how to deal with this because I think the problem is in my structures I think because I used another structure where I put everything in it the key, value ... but not the comparison function ```struct tree_t{
    const void *data;
    const void *key;
    struct tree_t* lchild;
    struct tree_t* rchild;
};```

Comment: Yes I changed the comparison functions and create a new binary tree using &comare_int, But I don't know how to deal with the base case in recursion of the insertion function because it still gives me segfault

Comment: ` printf("%p\n", bst->comparison);
    
    /*if ((bst->comparison(&key,&(bst->noeud->key))) < 0){
        
        bst->lchild = insertInBST(bst->lchild, key, value);
    }
    else if ((bst->comparison(&key,&(bst->noeud->key))) >= 0){
        bst->rchild = insertInBST(bst->rchild, key, value);
    }*/  ` The commented lines are causing segfault when I execute the function for the second time don't know why ?

Comment: In your insert `if (bst->noeud == NULL)` should be `if (bst == NULL)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Your comparison function is overly complicated `(*a_ > *b_) - (*a_ < *b_)` as you mix comparison (<, >) and arithmetic (-) operations.  @WhozCraig suggested (a < b) ? -1 : (b < a).
2. You need to define struct City.
3. You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` for malloc.
4. In main you are casting integers to pointers. The compiler warning for the first case is:

   warning: initialization of ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

   As in `int t = 15; int g = 13` and later `insertInBST(root, &t, &g)`
5. In main you use the wrong compare function (doubles instead of int).
6. I ran your code through gdb and it crashes in `if (bst->noeud == 0)` because `insertInBST(root, t, g)` invokes `bst->rchild = insertInBST(bst->rchild, key, value)` but bst->rchild is NULL.
7. In insertInBST, you only need to do the comparison once to figure out if you need the left or right branch.

Comment: *Don't* use (a-b) for order comparison in a C comparator function. It is a recipe for underflow, and consequently breaking any ordering algorithm. There's a reason you see people not doing that, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig What do you suggest instead?  I will be happy to update the answer.  Testing doubles for equality is also a no/no.

Comment: given argument a and b, returning less than zero on a < b, greater than zero on b < a, and zero on equivalence, you could use `return (a < b) ? -1 : (b < a);` . There are multiple ways to do this; the way the OP chose is one of them. I prefer using only one logical operator (less-than), but that comes from a lifetime of coding strict weak orderings.